# Error: EACCES: permission denied with forever

Tags: node.js, socket.io, forever, nodemon

I have a script in socket.io on Debian server.
I installed Forever and nodemon.

When i launch my script with nodemon or forever, it work perfectly.
But, when i push this command in a linux service, it's fail.

Here my service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Chat

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/mysite/web
ExecStart=/usr/bin/forever start /var/www/mysite/web/server.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=500ms
User=www-data
Group=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i checked the journalctl i have this error :

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/.forever/YEAA.log'
```

Here the complete error :

```
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: warn: --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: warn: --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: info: Forever processing file: /var/www/mysite/web/server.js
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: fs.js:646
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: ^
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/.forever/YEAA.log'
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: at Object.forever.startDaemon (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:460:14)
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: at /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:319:15
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: at /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:162:5
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: at /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever.js:412:11
déc. 27 13:45:05 vps32913 forever[7558]: at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe forever cannot access to .forever folder ?

Can you try with a chmod like this ?

```
chmod 644 /var/www/.forever
```

**EDIT**

If it doesn't works, you should probably launch `forever` as root user

Maybe with something like this ?

```
[Service]
...
User=root
Group=root
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it's the same error after reload of systemctl

déc. 27 14:40:13 vps32913 forever[17550]: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/.forever/T6hZ.log'

Comment: Are you launching forever as root user ?

Comment: When i launch manually forever (i m root) so it's perfect. 
For launch forever as root user, I confess I do not see how to do it...

Comment: Ok, i have change my service and put root. It's ok but now i have another problem.

The service is launch several times... 

déc. 27 14:54:22 vps32913 systemd[1]: chat.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.


déc. 27 14:54:22 vps32913 systemd[1]: chat.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
déc. 27 14:54:22 vps32913 systemd[1]: Failed to start chat.
déc. 27 14:54:22 vps32913 systemd[1]: Unit chat.service entered failed state.

Comment: yes, I thinks it's because your have a Restart=always and RestartSec=500ms. Can you try with deleting these two lines ?

Comment: I dont really understand why you want to launch forever as a service ?
Because forever is already a service which restart automatically if your server crashes. In fact, making a service is for replacing forever.. More info here : https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/